# Wordpress query for preview?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for an equivalent of getting a page/post with WP Query or get_posts e.g.:

```
$args=array(                        
  'category' => 1,
  'name' => 'my-page',
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => 1
);
$my_post = get_posts($args);
```

but I want this for a preview, only thing I have are the preview GET parameters:

```
?preview=true&preview_id=5&preview_nonce=b0d41a7fdb
```

The `preview_id` is actually the ID of the created post, not the id of the preview.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia irelevant, check my comment to your answer

Answer (score 6):

So I eventually found a possible answer - this should retrieve the latest preview or "revision":

```
$args = array(
  'post_status' => 'any',
  'post_parent' => intval($_GET['preview_id']),
  'post_type' => 'revision',
  'sort_column' => 'ID',
  'sort_order' => 'desc',
  'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$my_post = get_posts($args);
```